# How to use while loops in function in python?

Tags: python

```
def func(k): 
    print k
    i=0
    numbers = []
    while i<k:
        print "At the top i is %d" %i
        numbers.append(i*i*i)
        i=i+1
        print "The numbers are: " , numbers




y = raw_input("Give me a number")
m=func(y)
```

I am learning using functions and loops in python. As soon as i run this code it starts printing infinite numbers. I'm unable to find the issue with it.

Comment: Try `y = int(raw_input("Give me a number"))` and tell us how that goes :)

Answer (score 3):

The function `raw_input()` returns a string, and then you are passing that string onto the function `func()`.

In `func()` , in the condition for the `while` loop, you are checking an int against a string.

In Python 2.x , any `int` is always smaller than any string , hence the loop goes on forever. Example -

```
>>> 12323123123123121 < '1'
True
```

You should convert the input to an integer before giving it to the function (or directly when taking the input) . Example -

```
y = int(raw_input("Give me a number"))
```

Also, since you are expecting a return value from your function, you should return a value. Currently, you are not returning anything from the function. Example -

```
while i<k:
    ...
    i=i+1
    print "The numbers are: " , numbers
return numbers
```

---

In Python 3.x , this type of comparison is not allowed, if you try to compare string and int with that operator, you would get an error like - `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()` .

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of big problems with your code:

1. **your input is a string, not a number**
2. **there's no return statement**

To solve 1, you must first realize that `raw_input` gets... raw input; specifically in the form of a `str`. You must convert it to an int, float, whatever you want. I'll presume you want an integer input for sake of simplicity.

```
y = int(raw_input("Give me a number"))
```

Without a `return`, you can't return a value. In this case, you can't return the `m` that you want. I'll assume that you want to return `numbers` once your loop condition fails.

```
def func(k): 
  print k
  i=0
  numbers = []
  while i<k:
    print "At the top i is %d" %i
    numbers.append(i*i*i)
    i=i+1
    print "The numbers are: " , numbers
  return numbers
```

I wrote a little script to test -- here it is:

```
def func(k):
  print k
  i=0
  numbers = []
  while i<k:
    print "At the top i is %d" %i
    numbers.append(i*i*i)
    i=i+1
    print "The numbers are: " , numbers
  return numbers

hello = func(3)
print hello
```

The output I get is:

```
3
At the top i is 0
The numbers are:  [0]
At the top i is 1
The numbers are:  [0, 1]
At the top i is 2
The numbers are:  [0, 1, 8]
[0, 1, 8]
```